# Why isn't my ImageButton style being applied to my ImageButton?

Tags: android, android-styles

I have some styles set up to work on different API's (one for v21 and one for anything below that). I want to have a style for my ImageButton but it doesn't seem to be working out the way I expect.

The style for the v-21 is

```
<style name="BorderlessImageButton" parent="AppTheme.BorderlessImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/secondary_text</item>
</style>
```

The style that will be used for all other API's below v-21 is

```
<style name="BorderlessImageButton" parent="AppTheme.BorderlessImageButton"/>

<style name="AppTheme.BorderlessImageButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/borderless_button_background</item>
</style>
```

Here is my xml resource

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/date_picker"
    android:background="@null"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_today_white_24dp"
    android:theme="@style/BorderlessImageButton" />
```

If I run this on a device that has v-21 or v-22, the button doesn't visually react to my touch as I would expect using the ?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless. Also, on any device below v-21, the button still doesn't react to the selector resource I have set up for it.

```
res/color/borderless_button_background.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/accent" />
    <item android:color="@color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Please help me get my button to react properly to touch based on which API the user has on their device.

Thanks

Comment: You apply your style with `style="@style/BorderlessImageButton"`, `android:theme` is for activities

Comment: Holy moly, that's it. Make that an answer dude! I'll mark it as correct

Comment: Done. I put also a link with the docs, that helps too :-)

Comment: Thanks a ton. I have my head wrapped around styling views like this, but it seems like I haven't been applying it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply your style with

```
style="@style/BorderlessImageButton"
```

The attribute `android:theme` is used for activities, see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyAStyle).

---

**UPDATE**

Since Android 5.0, or using AppCompat 22.1.0+ (api 11+), you can also use a `ThemeOverlay` and use `android:theme` on single views. You can read about this technique [here](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/JXHKyhsWHAH). Thanks to Ian for this.

Comment: In fact, you **can** use `android:theme` on individual views, as explained in [this pro-tip](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/JXHKyhsWHAH). However, those don't use styles, but ideally a `ThemeOverlay` which more closely follows the model from activity styling.

Comment: Thanks, I put it in the answer for future readers. I also put a small comment in the blog post.